# Vue.js | Manually triggered events breaking model synchronization?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mvvm, frameworks, dom-events

I am having some issues with one of my modules.

Consider the following example:

```js
Vue.config.async = false; // if I remove this, it stays at initial value

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data: {
   value: 'initial value'
  },
  methods: {
    changeHandler: function () {
      console.log('changed!')
    }
  }
});

vm.value = 'value change 1';
vm.$el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
vm.value = 'value change 2';
vm.$el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

console.log(vm.value); // 'value change 1'
```

```html
<textarea id='test' v-model='value' v-on:change="changeHandler"></textarea>

<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
```

Why won't model (and view) update after dispatching a 'change' event right before I want to assign a new value?

Is this a problem with Vue or am I just doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You're working with the DOM when you should be working with the viewmodel. You've bound `value` to your textarea, and then you want to notice changes, right? Since you're modeling the textarea this way, you should `watch` the bound variable rather than the DOM element.

If you want to signal an event within Vue to trigger a handler, you should use [Vue events](http://vuejs.org/api/?#vm-dispatch), not DOM Events. As a general rule, strongly prefer manipulating your Vue over touching the DOM.

Setting `async` to `false` allows you to see all the changes, which otherwise happen so fast that some get debounced.

```js
Vue.config.async = false;

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data: {
    value: 'initial value'
  },
  watch: {
    value: function() {
      console.log('changed!')
    }
  }
});

vm.$on('valueChange', function() {
  console.log('value change!');
});

vm.value = 'value change 1';
vm.$dispatch('valueChange');
vm.value = 'value change 2';
vm.$dispatch('valueChange');

console.log(vm.value); // 'value change 2'
```

```html
<textarea id='test' v-model='value'></textarea>

<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I should have mentioned earlier that I need to do this for my module unit tests. So I really need that "change" event. 

Basically, my module has inner functionality that prevents a class from being added until there is a (native) change event. 

My real question is - how to invoke v-on:change and v-on:keyup handlers **manually** ?

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the `change` event is interfering with normal event processing. If you give each event a little bit of time (see the [`nextTick`](https://vuejs.org/api/#Vue-nextTick) calls in my snippet), things work out as expected.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data: {
    value: 'initial value'
  },
  methods: {
    changeHandler: function() {
      console.log('changed!')
    }
  }
});

vm.value = 'value change 1';
Vue.nextTick(() => vm.$el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')));
Vue.nextTick(() =>vm.value = 'value change 2');
Vue.nextTick(() => vm.$el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')));

console.log(vm.value); // 'value change 1'
```

```html
<textarea id='test' v-model='value' v-on:change="changeHandler"></textarea>

<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
```