# vue.js element selected by focus is not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have a listener to check what input was selected at last to add some kind of string/variable later into it.

```
created: function () {
    document.addEventListener('focusin', this.focusChanged);
}

focusChanged(event) {
    if (event.target.id !== 'variable-search') {
        this.lastElement = event.target;
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine, and when I click on an input field `this.lastElement` gets updated with the focused element. All these inputs have a `v-model` which can be a string in an object or just a plain string.

Now the thing is when I try to update the value by:

```
this.lastElement.value += variable;
```

Vue won't detect its changes, also in the Vue Developer tools the string won't get updated. But in the input field it does get updated. So this should be a reactivity thing.

When I add a new character into the input field (v-model) it does update again. So it's just when I update the string by `this.lastElement` it won't register its changes.

The thing is that the input fields are dynamic, so I don't know how many input fields are here and how many lists etc. So I need Vue to re-render the variable after the value of `lastElement` is updated.

**Edit**

I just tried it with an @focus here an example

```
<input v-model="testVar" @focus="lastElement = testVar">
```

If I update `lastElement` later on it doesn't update it for `testVar` but just for `lastElement`.

Comment: You need to update the `lastElement` value through the binding with the v-model, because `this.lastElement` stores the reference to the dom element, but its value is controlled by the vue model.

Comment: @thefallen that's just not possible in this case because I can't just access the v-model directly.

Comment: @JelmerdeVries Why can't you use `v-on:focus` instead?

Comment: I've tried that as well. It just doesn't register the changes because the element it's value is changed by javascript. I'm trying a different approach right now. I'll keep you guys updated, never had such an issue with Vue haha.

Comment: I just tried a @focus again and set lastElement to the current v-model element. So lets say I have an input: '<input v-model="test" @focus="lastElement = test"> if I update lastElement value after that it doesn't update the test..

Comment: Could you show us the code you used when you tried `@focus`?

Comment: @DelenaMalan updated it!

Comment: Perhaps it it better if you would explain what you want to achieve. You generate some input fields dynamically and then what is supposed to happen?

Comment: It's a dynamic mail system where you can edit mails. In these mails you can use some kind of variables like *address*. These variables can be typed just directly in the input fields or you click on a button which contains *address* for example. If you click on this button it adds just *address* to the value. If you click this button right now with the first version it does update the input text but it doesn't get registered in Vue. So they see "test string *address*" while vue registers just "test string", if they type anything after *address* it will update right again. Ty for helping btw

Comment: You manipulate dom elements via dom functions. This is the reason why these elements do not get registered in vue. You should have some data structure in your component, which gets rendered in the template. When you press a button, you should add data to the internal data structure. If you do that, it will get rendered automatically.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to dynamically add values for certain keys to an arbitrary data structure (in this case email). It can be done via an input field (where you display an input field for each possible key), or there is a button, which will add a predefined value for a certain key. Is this correct?

Comment: After you modify the value in `lastElement`, you need to have `lastElement` [dispatch an `input` or `change` event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39367533/392102) so Vue recognizes that something happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing values in DOM elements programmatically does not cause DOM events to fire. `v-model` relies on `input` (or `change` when using `.lazy`) events to update its bound variable. If you dispatch those events when you update the value in an input, the variable will react.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: ['one','two','three']
  },
  methods: {
    addAddress() {
      this.lastElement.value += 'address';
      this.lastElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
      this.lastElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    },
    focusChanged(event) {
      this.lastElement = event.target;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item, index in items">
    <input v-model="items[index]" @focus="focusChanged">
    {{item}}
  </div>
  <button type="button" @click="addAddress">+address</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You're a hero! Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `ref` [attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) to each of the inputs and use the ref to update their values. For example, an input element could be:

```
<input v-model="testVar" ref="input1" id="input1" @focus="focusChanged">
```

In your methods:

```
 methods: {
      focusChanged(event) {
            if (event.target.id !== 'variable-search') {
                this.lastElement = event.target.id;
            }
        },
 }
```

And where you want to update the value: `this.$refs[this.lastElement].value += variable;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try this out!

Comment: I think that this is not an optimal solution, as the vuejs docs advise to use ref only in edge cases.

Comment: Okay this turns out to do the same, it does update the text again but vue doesn't register it. So the variable get's added to the value of the input on screen but vue still has the old string. If you update the string with 1 character it does get updated right (but that's the same as in my versions)..